# What are the best practices and efficient methods for optimizing an image cropping code in Python, using libraries like OpenCV or Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, playback

I have this code in Pillow that perfectly crops an image. For example, I have content with different colors against the same background, and this code crops it to the smallest possible size with a 32-pixel margin.

However, it's very slow! It takes almost 12 seconds on the machine where it runs (Cloud Run 4 vCPU with 4 GiB of RAM), whereas the Chromium process, which launches a full browser and interprets HTML and CSS, takes only 3 seconds.

So, I'd like to know what I can do to optimize this process.

I understand that it's pixel-perfect and, given its nature, takes more time, but 12 seconds seems excessively long.

Alternatively, I could use OpenCV, or I might employ some technique involving both JavaScript and Python to determine the ideal size for cropping, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Full image WITHOUT crop: https://delduca-to25gludpq-uc.a.run.app/get

```
def trim(buffer, margin=32, trim_color="#92b88a"):
    with PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer)).convert("RGB") as image:
        width, height = image.size

        left, top, right, bottom = 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1

        trim_color_rgb = tuple(int(trim_color[i : i + 2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))

        while left < width:
            column = [image.getpixel((left, y)) for y in range(height)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in column):
                left += 1
            else:
                break

        while top < height:
            row = [image.getpixel((x, top)) for x in range(width)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in row):
                top += 1
            else:
                break

        while right > left:
            column = [image.getpixel((right, y)) for y in range(height)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in column):
                right -= 1
            else:
                break

        while bottom > top:
            row = [image.getpixel((x, bottom)) for x in range(width)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in row):
                bottom -= 1
            else:
                break

        left = max(left - margin, 0)
        top = max(top - margin, 0)
        right = min(right + margin, width - 1)
        bottom = min(bottom + margin, height - 1)

        return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

Comment: as I know `get_pixel()` can be very slow. Maybe you should convert image to `numpy.array` and run some code without using `for`-loops - first `column = array[0:y, right]` (without `for`-loop) and probably `column == trim_color_rgb` (without `for`-loop)

Comment: Please click [edit] and ensure you provide a proper [mcve]. That means code I can run without needing to guess what your `import` statements look like and with your input image, your current output image and your expected output image. Thank you.

Comment: Every python programmer knows what are the needed imports. I don’t know if you know, but I cannot post only code, that why I had a lot of text on the question.

Comment: @furas mind to post an example?

Comment: I'm trying to help you, not argue. I am a volunteer - I don't get paid,  but have assisted 14 million programmers in the last 10 years. The site requires and expects people to provide [mcve] so answerers don't waste their time guessing what askers mean, or trying to find datasets. That's how it works. If you would like folks to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell any modern IDE will import to you. Asking for one line of import is totally pointless

Comment: That wasn't what I asked for though. I asked for a [mcve] with images. I repeat, I am trying to help you - I have answered over 6,000 questions without asking for any to be answered. I am here to help, not argue.

Comment: @MarkSetchell have you read the question? There is a image as example.

Comment: better create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and run. It doesn't matter that `Every python programmer knows what are the needed imports.` because there are other questions with better code - so we may go to other question instead of wasting time to convert your code to `minimal working code`. BTW: I don't use any modern IDE but normal text editor.

Comment: you ask to post example - I already posted in previous comment. `column = array[0:y, right]` (without for-loop) and probably `column == trim_color_rgb`. To show something more I would have to create some `minimal working code`. Maybe I will do it or maybe I will go to other questions - I don't know yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to optimize your image cropping code in Python: using PIL’s `getbbox()` method or using OpenCV’s findContours () and `boundingRect()` functions.

Using PIL’s `getbbox()` method:

The `getbbox()` method of the Image class returns the bounding box of the non-zero regions in the image. This method is much faster than looping over the pixels manually. You can then use the `crop()` method to crop the image according to the bounding box, and add the margin as needed. Here is an example of how to use this method:

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open ('./myimage.png').convert ('RGB')
bbox = img.getbbox ()
img = img.crop (bbox)
width, height = img.size
left = max (0, bbox [0] - margin)
top = max (0, bbox [1] - margin)
right = min (width, bbox [2] + margin)
bottom = min (height, bbox [3] + margin)
img = img.crop ((left, top, right, bottom))
img.save ('./myimage_cropped.png')
```

---

Using OpenCV’s `findContours()` and `boundingRect()` functions:

OpenCV is a library for computer vision and image processing. OpenCV has many functions for image manipulation, such as `findContours()`, which can find the contours of the objects in the image, and `boundingRect()`, which can calculate the bounding rectangle of a set of points. You can then use the `rectangle()` function to draw the bounding rectangle on the image, and the `imwrite()` function to save the image. Here is an example of how to use OpenCV for image cropping:

```py
import cv2
img = cv2.imread ('./myimage.png', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold (img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours (thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = max (contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect (cnt)
x = max (0, x - margin)
y = max (0, y - margin)
w = min (w + 2 * margin, img.shape [1] - x)
h = min (h + 2 * margin, img.shape [0] - y)
img = cv2.rectangle (img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
img = img [y:y + h, x:x + w]
cv2.imwrite ('./myimage_cropped.png', img)
```

Comment: I tested your code with image from question. There is problem because Image has green background (`trim_color`) and probably it needs to remove background before `img.getbbox()`? Do you know how to do this fast? Can you describe it in answer?

Answer (score 1):

As I know `get_pixel()` can be very slow. You should convert image to `numpy.array`

```
numpy_array = np.array(image)
```

and run some code without using `for`-loops

```
column = array[0:y, right]
```

```
if (column == trim_color_rgb).all():
```

And rest of code can be the same.

I had to make `minimal working code` to check it and

- your version takes me `25 to 30 seconds`
- using `numpy` it takes about `1 second`

---

Full working code which I used for test:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def trim_1(buffer, margin=32, trim_color="#92b88a"):

    with Image.open('logo.png').convert("RGB") as image:
    #with Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer)).convert("RGB") as image:
        width, height = image.size

        left, top, right, bottom = 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1

        trim_color_rgb = tuple(int(trim_color[i : i + 2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))

        while left < width:
            column = [image.getpixel((left, y)) for y in range(height)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in column):
                left += 1
            else:
                break

        while top < height:
            row = [image.getpixel((x, top)) for x in range(width)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in row):
                top += 1
            else:
                break

        while right > left:
            column = [image.getpixel((right, y)) for y in range(height)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in column):
                right -= 1
            else:
                break

        while bottom > top:
            row = [image.getpixel((x, bottom)) for x in range(width)]
            if all(pix == trim_color_rgb for pix in row):
                bottom -= 1
            else:
                break

        left = max(left - margin, 0)
        top = max(top - margin, 0)
        right = min(right + margin, width - 1)
        bottom = min(bottom + margin, height - 1)

        print(left, top, right, bottom)
        return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

def trim_2(buffer, margin=32, trim_color="#92b88a"):

    with Image.open('logo.png').convert("RGB") as image:
    #with Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer)).convert("RGB") as image:
        width, height = image.size

        numpy_array = np.array(image)   #  convert to `numpy array`
        #height, width, _ = numpy_array.shape 

        left, top, right, bottom = 0, 0, width - 1, height - 1

        trim_color_rgb = tuple(int(trim_color[i : i + 2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))

        while left < width:
            column = numpy_array[:,left]
            if (column == trim_color_rgb).all():
                left += 1
            else:
                break

        while top < height:
            row = numpy_array[top,:]
            if (row == trim_color_rgb).all():
                top += 1
            else:
                break

        while right > left:
            column = numpy_array[:,right]
            if (column == trim_color_rgb).all():
                right -= 1
            else:
                break

        while bottom > top:
            row = numpy_array[bottom,:]
            if (row == trim_color_rgb).all():
                bottom -= 1
            else:
                break

        left = max(left - margin, 0)
        top = max(top - margin, 0)
        right = min(right + margin, width - 1)
        bottom = min(bottom + margin, height - 1)

        print(left, top, right, bottom)
        
        return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

start = time.time()
print('running ...')
result = trim_1(None)
end = time.time()
print('trim_1 time:', end - start)
result.save('trim_1.png')

start = time.time()
print('running ...')
result = trim_2(None)
end = time.time()
print('trim_2 time:', end - start)
result.save('trim_2.png')
```

Result:

```
running ...
668 48 1227 551
trim_1 time: 25.654032468795776

running ...
668 48 1227 551
trim_2 time: 0.8261435031890869
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I have found a better alternative (may be not fast or faster than yours, I have not mensured)

Comment: @Rodrigo I saw your answer - but you should describe it to make it useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

A little bird whose name cannot be spoken here gave me this solution, and it executes in less than a second!

```
def trim(buffer, margin=32, trim_color="#92b88a"):
    with PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer)).convert("RGB") as image:
        data = np.array(image)
        trim_color_rgb = tuple(int(trim_color[i : i + 2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5))

        non_trim_rows = np.where(np.any(data != trim_color_rgb, axis=(1, 2)))[0]
        non_trim_cols = np.where(np.any(data != trim_color_rgb, axis=(0, 2)))[0]

        left = max(0, non_trim_cols[0] - margin)
        top = max(0, non_trim_rows[0] - margin)
        right = min(data.shape[1] - 1, non_trim_cols[-1] + margin)
        bottom = min(data.shape[0] - 1, non_trim_rows[-1] + margin)

        return PIL.Image.fromarray(data[top:bottom, left:right])
```